# I can't find a problem with file input and output(compile error)

Tags: c++

I want to put the information in the file in an array.
However, there is an error on i1File.
The value in i1File is the name of the people.
I want to put the value in the stna arrangement in I1File.
The value in i2File is 1 or 2.
I want to put the value in I2File in stngn arrangement.
Errors occur in the input function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
#define MAX_SIZE 1000



class seat {
    string stna[100]; // 학생들이름
    int stgn[100] = { 0, }; //학생들 성별
    int inputint;
    string inputString;
    //char inputString[MAX_SIZE];

public:

    int numbern = 0;// 학생수

    void inputinformation(void);
    void mainchang(void);
    void setseat(void);
    void zolottery(void);
    void danglottery(void);
    void checkrecord(void);
    void setmember(void);
};


void seat::mainchang()  
{

        cout << "┌─────────────────────── 채 메인 화면 ────────────────────────┐" << endl;
        cout << "│                                                             │" << endl;
        cout << "│                                                             │" << endl;
        cout << "│                        1.자리 배치                          │" << endl;
        cout << "│                                                             │" << endl;
        cout << "│                        2.조 추첨                            │" << endl;
        cout << "│                                                             │" << endl;
        cout << "│                        3.당번 추첨                          │" << endl;
        cout << "│                                                             │" << endl;
        cout << "│                        4.회원 설정                          │" << endl;
        cout << "│                                                             │" << endl;
        cout << "│                        5.기록 확인                          │" << endl;
        cout << "│                                                             │" << endl;
        cout << "│                        6.회원 설정                          │" << endl;
        cout << "│                                                             │" << endl;
        cout << "│                        7.종 료                              │" << endl;
        cout << "│                                                             │" << endl;
        cout << "└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘" << endl;
}
void seat::setseat() {
};
void seat::zolottery() {
    system("cls");
    int zonumber;
    cout << "조 인원은 몇명입니까?" << endl;
    cin >> zonumber;

};
void seat::checkrecord() {};

void seat::danglottery() {
    system("cls");
    cout << "당번 추첨 중입니다. □ □ □ □ □..." << endl;
    Sleep(300);
    system("cls");
    cout << "당번 추첨 중입니다. ■ □ □ □ □.." << endl ;
    Sleep(300);
    system("cls");
    cout << "당번 추첨 중입니다. ■ ■ □ □ □...." << endl ;
    Sleep(300);
    system("cls");
    cout << "당번 추첨 중입니다. ■ ■ ■ □ □.." << endl ;
    Sleep(300);
    system("cls");
    cout << "당번 추첨 중입니다. ■ ■ ■ ■ □..." << endl ;
    Sleep(300);
    system("cls");
    cout << "당번 추첨 중입니다. ■ ■ ■ ■ ■" << endl ;
    Sleep(200);
    system("cls");

    int r = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    r = rand() % numbern + 1;
    ifstream nuFile("number.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbern; i++) {
        nuFile.getline(inputString, 100);
        if (i + 1 == r) {
            system("cls");
            PlaySound("환영드럼.wav", NULL, SND_ASYNC | SND_LOOP);
            cout << "┌─────────────────── 추첨 결과 ───────────────────┐" << endl;
            cout << "│            "<<inputString << "님이 당첨되었습니다" << "            │" <<endl;
            cout << "└─────────────────────────────────────────────────┘" << endl;
            Sleep(2600);
            PlaySound(0, 0, 0);
            Sleep(1000);
            nuFile.close();
            break;  
        }
    }

};

void seat::inputinformation(void) {
    ifstream i1File("number.txt");
    ifstream i2File("gender.txt");
    int n = 0;
    while (!i1File.eof() && !i2File.eof()) {
        i1File.getline(inputString, 100); 
        stna[n] = inputString;
        i2File.getline(inputint, 100); 
        stgn[n] = inputint; 
        n++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numbern; i++) {
        cout << stna[i] << ",  " << stgn[i];
    }
    system("cls");
    Sleep(10000);

    //stna[100][100]; // 학생들이름
    //stgn[100][1]; //학생들 성별
}
void seat::setmember(void) {
    system("cls");
    int input;
    cout << "┌─────────────────────── 채 설정 화면 ────────────────────────┐" << endl;
    cout << "│                                                             │" << endl;
    cout << "│                                                             │" << endl;
    cout << "│                        1.이름 설정                          │" << endl;
    cout << "│                                                             │" << endl;
    cout << "│                        2.성별 설정                          │" << endl;
    cout << "│                                                             │" << endl;
    cout << "│                                                             │" << endl;
    cout << "└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘" << endl;
    cout << "원하시는 선택지를 선택해주세요. ";
    cin >> input;
    system("cls");
    if (input == 1) {
        string name;
        system("cls");
        cout << "학생수를 입력해주세요.";
        cin >> numbern;
        ofstream outFile("number.txt");
        system("cls");
        for (int i = 0; i < numbern; i++) {
            cout << i + 1 << "번째 사람의 성함을 입력해주세요" << endl;
            cout << "이름: ";
            cin >> name;
            outFile << name << endl;
            system("cls");
        }
        outFile.close();
    }
    else if (input == 2) {
        int gender;
        system("cls");
        ofstream outFile("gender.txt");
        ifstream inFile("number.txt");
        system("cls");

        for (int i = 0; i < numbern; i++) {
            inFile.getline(inputString, 100);
            cout << inputString << "님의 성별을 입력해주세요.(남자 = 0 여자 = 1)" << endl;
            cout << "성별: ";
            cin >> gender;
            outFile << gender << endl;
            system("cls");
        }
        inFile.close();
        outFile.close();

        inputinformation();
    }
}

class student {
public:

    int gender; // 0남자 1여자

    int seatnumber; //고정 번호 // 없으면 0
};

int main(void) {
    seat seat;
    while (1) {
    again:
        int input, snsn;
        seat.mainchang();
        cout << "학생들의 수를 입력해주세요.";
        cin >> snsn;
        seat.numbern = snsn;`enter code here`
        cout << "원하시는 선택지를 선택해주세요. ";
        cin >> input;
        if (input == 1) seat.setseat();
        else if (input == 2) seat.zolottery();
        else if (input == 3) seat.danglottery();
        else if (input == 4) seat.setmember();
        else if (input == 5) seat.checkrecord();
        else if (input == 6) seat.setmember();
        else if (input == 7) break;
        else {
            system("cls");
            cout << "다시 입력해주세요";
            goto again;
        }
        seat.mainchang();
        system("cls");
    }
}
```

Receive all the information in the file in an array.

Comment: What sort of errors do you get in your input function?  Compilation errors?  Runtime errors?  [Edit] your question to include these details.

Comment: I like the progress bar that shows the user how long they need to wait for your program to finish doing nothing of value.

Comment: Use `std::getline(...)` not `ifstream::getline(...)` That is the source of all of your compiler errors.